# Is it possible to add SVG images to a web page through CSS?

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics

I just started experimenting with SVG in web pages, and I discovered that it is only possible to add SVG images into HTML using `<object />` tags, not `<img />` like I would have expected. Most of the time, I add graphics to web pages through CSS because they are part of the presentation of the site, not the content.

I know it is possible to apply CSS *to* SVG, but is it possible to add a vector image to an HTML element using purely CSS?

Answer (score 5):

SVG is supported in `<img>` and in CSS (list-image, background-image, content) since Opera 9. Opera 10 is better still. Webkit/Safari supports svg in `<img>` too.

Some [examples here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080420175708/http://my.opera.com/SVGraphics/forums/topic.dml?id=203830), a couple more at [dev.opera.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20071006010144/http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/new-development-techniques-using-opera-k/) and [annevankesteren.nl](http://annevankesteren.nl)

If you're looking for inline svg examples, have a look at [Sam Ruby's site](http://intertwingly.net/).

Answer (score 4):

You can try to reference an SVG file with the content property, but I don't think it's supported. If it was supported it would look like this:

```
.putapicturehere:before {
  content: url(mysvgfile.svg);
}
```

This definitely won't work in IE - it might work in the newest Firefox.

I always [reference quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html) for css browser support questions.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it doesn't work in IE. My target audience is going to be iPhone/iPod touch safari browsers.

Comment: Let us know if it works on the iPhone. SVG is a cool technology - I hope it catches on more!

Comment: Can you manipulate svg properties, eg. fill in this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make a little CSS-helper JavaScript to read the image out of an offscreen img and put it into your object tag.  That way you can still control with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Opera 9 and WebKit (== Safari & Chrome) do it on PCs, and rumour has it, that FF3.5 will also be able.

Actually, since Apple added SVG support to iPhone's Safari just half a year ago, I'm not sure, if it works, but it's worth a try.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried, almost a year ago, it didn't work. You can, however, already mix svg and xhtml markup. Only problem there is that the page has to have correct mime type (application-xml or something like that) or browsers will ignore the svg.

Inline svg is not a perfect solution if you want strict separation of content and presentation, but is seemed to be the most supported way of using svg.